# Django Admin Page: Help Text for Model Methods?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have a model method in Django that I am displaying on an admin page just like I would a model field.  With a field, I can just add a help_text argument to it to give a description of what the field is and what the user should put into it.  However, with a model method, help_text does not work.  Adding the attribute short_description changes the way the method name is displayed, which is sort of okay, but I'm looking for a way to add a few sentences of description beneath the method value that is displayed.  Is there any way to do this natively, or would I have to resort to overriding admin templates or something?  (Which I do not think is worth it for something this minor).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JS.

Replace `ID-OF-THE-FIELD` with the actual id of the desired field.

```js
(function($) {
    var myField = $('#ID-OF-THE-FIELD'); 
    // find the id of the desired field by doing
    // Right-Click > Inspect element

    var help = $('<p class="help">A very long help text</p>');
    help.insertAfter(myField);

})(django.jQuery);
```

Put this code into a JS file and supply this file using [`class Media`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions) of your `ModelAdmin` class.